# 例外処理で次の工程に進む方法

Tags: ruby

例外処理について質問させていただきます。

計算式

```
a = d + f + g
b = h + j
c=a+b
```

上の計算をする場合d,f,g,h,jは変数で、 aの計算でエラーが出た時（例えばgでNoMethodError）にはaの計算はそこで終了(fで終了)し、b・cに進みたいのですが例外処理のrescue部分に何を書いていいのか思いつきません。

何かいい方法がありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `d` で例外発生したらどうなってほしいんですか？　そういうの整理しないと実際のコードに落とせないですよ。

Comment: すみません、言葉足らずでした。d,f,g,h,jは外部から取得すしてくるもので、d,fは必ず数値が返ってくるのですが、gは数値が返ってきたり、数値が割り当てられてなくnilで返ってきたりするので、基本的にd,f,hには例外は発生しないものです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 例外処理のrescue部分に何を書いていいのか思いつきません。

以下の`begin 〜 rescue; end`のように何も書かなければ良いと思います。

```
a = d = f= h = j = 0       # 実行可能とするため、g以外は初期化しておく
begin
  a = d + f + g
rescue; end                     # 例外を無視
b = h + j
c = a + b
```

参考情報:

- [How to “ignore” caught exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556327/how-to-ignore-caught-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

例外のあるプログラミング言語において、基本的に、プログラミングのミスに起因する例外と、そうでない例外(ファイルが壊れてた、ネットワークがつながらなかった、など)があります。

NoMethodError は、基本的にプログラム記述のミスに起因する例外です。この処理が、メソッドの中のどの部分で表れているのか分からないので、推測になりますが、たとえば:

- if 文でのみ g の変数への代入が行われている。条件次第では g への代入が行われない場合がある

  - => g をメソッドの最初に 0 で初期化しておきましょう。
- method_missing を用いたような、利用可能なメソッドが動的に変化するオブジェクトの中での処理中のできごとである。

  - => `respond_to? :g` で、 g というメソッドが存在するかどうかチェックする

など、基本的にプログラム側で対処した方がベターです。